# Simple session based data caching for spring mvc 3

Tags: java, spring, session, caching, spring-mvc

I need simple, preferable session based cache, for our Spring MVC **3.1** app. I know in 3.1 introduced cashing abstraction, but as far as I know, it is application wide caching. We need something simpler, for caching user grid data. I don't mined even using it directly, as long, as it has simple interface.

Any one used something like that? Is there any good lib? Or is there way to force Spring cache abstraction to cache data for current session only? Or am I doomed to write it by myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Session scoped bean

If you don't mind explicit solution, create a bean with `session` scope and inject it to your controller.

If you don't forget to wrap it with scoped proxy (`<aop:scoped-proxy/>`) you can
just place your cached data in fields of that bean. Spring will automatically create one instance of that bean per each HTTP session and store it there.

#### Caching abstraction

On the other hand I think Spring caching abstraction might work for you - SPeL gives you access to HTTP environment so you probably construct cache key declaratively (in annotation) based on current user session id or some other attribute like user name.

Comment: **session scoped bean** is something I've considered, but rather as a way to implement simple caching by myself. And I really don't want to reinvent the wheel:)

**Caching abstraction** with keys containing session id? Well, its interesting, but it still kips data application-wide, and now, even more data if user keeps logging in and out few times before old cached data is cleared. With sessions, at least, I know it will be thrown away as soon as session is invalidated.

Comment: If you go with caching abstraction approach (I am not sure whether this is possible but worth trying) you can easily plug your own cache by implementing `org.springframework.cache.support.AbstractCacheManager`.

Comment: Jeah, but still, it is implementing it by myself and probably will take more time :? On the other hand, it would have same interface :)